# reverse lookup private zone

Tags: dns

how could I forward reverse lookups in unbound for `172.0.0.0/8`, it works `10.0.0.0/8` without problems. My working unbound.conf looks like this:

```
.....
.....
access-control: 10.0.0.0/8 allow
access-control: 172.16.0.0/12 allow
access-control: 192.168.0.0/16 allow
access-control: 127.0.0.0/8 allow
access-control: ::1 allow
.....
.....
local-zone: "10.IN-ADDR.ARPA" transparent
local-zone: "16.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA" transparent
local-zone: "19.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA" transparent
local-zone: "20.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA" transparent
local-zone: "29.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA" transparent
local-zone: "30.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA" transparent
local-zone: "31.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA" transparent
local-zone: "168.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA" transparent
forward-zone:
  name: "."
  forward-addr: ns01.domain.local
  forward-addr: ns02.domain.local
```

I would like to modify it this way but it doesn't work. I just want to avoid adding all networks:

```
.....
.....
access-control: 10.0.0.0/8 allow
access-control: 172.0.0.0/8 allow
access-control: 192.168.0.0/16 allow
access-control: 127.0.0.0/8 allow
access-control: ::1 allow
.....
.....
local-zone: "10.IN-ADDR.ARPA" transparent
local-zone: "172.IN-ADDR.ARPA" transparent
local-zone: "168.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA" transparent
forward-zone:
  name: "."
  forward-addr: ns01.domain.local
  forward-addr: ns02.domain.local
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just an observation, `172.0.0.0/8` contains both public _and_ private network address space. Do you want the `172.16.0.0/20` private network instead?

Comment: @datUser  thanks for the notification, I missed that completely! You are right, it cannot work this way, well the 172.16.0.0/12 is what I need, there fore I am afraid I have to add all private networks separately! or is there a another way? I thought with the forward-zone config, reverse lookups will be forwarded as well, but unfortunately not, and I don't get it why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All subnets in `172.16.0.0/12` should be added separately as follows:

```
.....
.....
access-control: 10.0.0.0/8 allow
access-control: 172.16.0.0/12 allow
access-control: 192.168.0.0/16 allow
access-control: 127.0.0.0/8 allow
access-control: ::1 allow
.....
.....
local-zone: "10.IN-ADDR.ARPA" transparent
local-zone: "16.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA" transparent
local-zone: "17.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA" transparent
.....
.....
.....
local-zone: "30.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA" transparent
local-zone: "31.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA" transparent
local-zone: "168.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA" transparent
forward-zone:
  name: "."
  forward-addr: ns01.domain.local
  forward-addr: ns02.domain.local
```

I will replace unbound with dnsmasq. Thanks a lot!